# Limited number of SQL Query selectors

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I can't figure out what is wrong with my query. I have three elements that control the order of posts: `quartier`, `block` and `number`. And it is working well.

I want to add a fourth named `street`. When I do so, nothing is fetched. I thought maybe there is a problem with `street`, but if for example I leave `street` but remove `block`, it is working again and uses `street` appropriately.

My conclusion is that the database only accepts a limited number of selectors per query. Is that true? Or am I missing something?

```
$query = "SELECT `wp_posts`.`post_title` , `wp_posts`.`ID` , `end`.`meta_value` AS `enddate` , `start`.`meta_value` as `startdate`, `quartier`.`meta_value` AS `thequartier`, `street`.`meta_value` AS `thestreet`, `number`.`meta_value` AS `thenumber`, `block`.`meta_value` AS `theblock`
        FROM `wp_posts` , `wp_postmeta` AS `end` , `wp_postmeta` AS `start` , `wp_postmeta` AS `quartier`, `wp_postmeta` AS `street`, `wp_postmeta` AS `number`, `wp_postmeta` AS `block`

        WHERE `wp_posts`.`post_type` = 'listing'

        AND `wp_posts`.`ID` = `end`.`post_id`
        AND `wp_posts`.`ID` = `start`.`post_id`
        AND `wp_posts`.`ID` = `quartier`.`post_id`
        AND `wp_posts`.`ID` = `street`.`post_id`
        AND `wp_posts`.`ID` = `block`.`post_id`
        AND `wp_posts`.`ID` = `number`.`post_id`

        AND `end`.`meta_key` = 'theend'
        AND `end`.`meta_value` >= '".time()."'

        AND `start`.`meta_key` = 'thestart'
        AND `start`.`meta_value` <= '".time()."'

        AND `quartier`.`meta_key` = 'quartier'
        AND `street`.`meta_key` = 'street'
        AND `number`.`meta_key` = 'number'
        AND `block`.`meta_key` = 'block'

        AND `wp_posts`.`post_status` = 'publish'

        GROUP BY `wp_posts`.`ID`
        ORDER BY `thequartier` + 0 ASC";
        $calendar = $wpdb->get_results($query, ARRAY_A);


        foreach ($calendar as $key => $row) {
            $thequartier[$key]  = $row['thequartier'];
            $thestreet[$key] = $row['thestreet'];
            $theblock[$key] = $row['theblock'];
            $thenumber[$key] = $row['thenumber'];
        }

        // Sort the data with volume descending, edition ascending
        array_multisort($thequartier, SORT_ASC, $theblock, SORT_ASC, $thestreet, SORT_ASC, $thenumber, SORT_ASC, $calendar);
```

Update: I found the solution for my problem, adding the following line to allow the excessive amount of selectors:

```
$wpdb->query("SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1");
```

Comment: if you only have `AND` conditions, you don't need parentheses. And once you take those out, you'll see you have condition collisions

Comment: Thanks for your input. I removed all parentheses and cleaned the code a little but can not find those collisions you are mentionning

Comment: you get collision at, for instance `wp_posts.ID` which needs to be (at the same time) equal to 6 values

Comment: Also, you might want to use `LEFT JOIN` on those tables

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I feel like I'm going in the right direction but it somehow doesn't work yet. I'm adding a new code to the post.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Thanks @Strawberry, I added a SQLFiddle with a simple example of my problem